# open a query that is based on a form field in access?

Tags: ms-access

I have a query that get a value from a query field. once I open the form and choose the value and I open the query it does open with no problem. I want to put a button in the same form that will allow me to open the query. Once I put the button and use the button wizard to make it open the query I get this issue once I press on the button:

[image]

[image]

The query:

```
SELECT Courses.Course_Id AS رقم_الدورة, Courses.Course_Name AS اسم_الدورة, 
Courses.Date_Course AS تاريخ_الدورة
FROM Courses INNER JOIN Colleges ON Courses.college_Id = Colleges.college_Id
WHERE Forms![FormName]![colleges].Value=Colleges.college_Name;
```

Note once I open the form and open the query I get no result. but once I close the form and open the query, the query will ask me to type in the input manually and once I type in the input manually I get the right result. But once I open the the form it wont ask to input because it should take the value from the combobox colleges and it do but I think it takes something wrong knowing that the combobox contain text.

Comment: Insert here you query. There is no way to help you if we do not see the code.

Comment: @Vlado updated the question

Comment: Try to replace the non-Latin characters.

Comment: I did same result nothing.

Comment: See first if the query works without the WHERE clause. If so the problem is after WHERE. Honestly I have never seen putting it in the order you have there. I would put it `Colleges.college_Name = Forms![FormName]![colleges].Value` but your script should work as well, I guess. (Hopefully you replace FormName with the real name)

Comment: Replace `FormName` with name of your actual form?

Comment: @krishKM yes i did

Answer (score 0):

The issue I had is that the comboBox by default contain of 2 columns 0 and 1 and in the query by it self it is not possible to specify the column as I tried to specifying the column using  or ![Column(1)] or even .Column(1) but none of them work and I search more this features is no more allowed since access 2013 in the query which means I should use VB to resolve it but as I continue to search I was able to do it by using a textbox so I created a textbox that read the information from the combobox and as I did that I was able to read the information from the textbox in my query